# Oracle SQL - Replace space/alpanumeric/non-alphanumeric with space and replace with word?

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

Hi I want to replace following examples with the following:

- **(LTRIM)** Replace any space at the beginning before first Alphanumerical character
- **(RTRIM)** Replace any space at the end after last Alphanumerical character
- Replace any non-alpha numerical with space
- Replace any empty (not null) with word "UNKNOWN"
- In case of only space replace all spaces with word "UNKNOWN"

```
'    abc  ' -> 'abc'
'abc      ' -> 'abc'
'  abc    ' -> 'abc'
'!ab c  ? ' -> 'ab c'
' a b c   ' -> 'a b c' 
'a!b?c  $ ' -> 'a b c'
'         ' -> 'UNKNOWN'
''          -> 'UNKNOWN'
null        -> null
```

These are the queries I'm working on but I'm not getting anywhere:

```
select 
'-|&@/,.‘“<>():;' as default1,
translate(SUBSTR(MAX ('-|&@/,.‘“<>():;'),1,70), '-|&@/,.‘“<>():;', '               ') as formatted1
from dual;


select trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(' a b cdefgh ' , '[[:space:]]*',''), '(.)', '\1 UNK' )) as formatted from dual;

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM('    NEXT LEVEL EMPLOYEE    ')) from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Replace any empty (not null) with word "UNKNOWN"

This is impossible as, in Oracle, there are no empty strings as an empty string is stored as `NULL`.

Apart from that impossibility, you can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN value IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE COALESCE(
              TRIM(
                BOTH ' ' FROM
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  value,
                  '[^A-Za-z0-9]',
                  ' '
                )
              ),
              'UNKNOWN'
            )
       END AS updated_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT '    abc  ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc      ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '  abc    ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '!ab c  ? ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ' a b c   ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a!b?c  $ ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '         ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT null FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| abc | abc |
| abc | abc |
| abc | abc |
| !ab c ? | ab c |
| a b c | a b c |
| a!b?c $ | a b c |
|  | UNKNOWN |
| *null* | *null* |
| *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IF76kQw3)